# Magento In Store Pickup Restrict Regions

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to restrict my in store pickup to only one state (Illinois). Below is my system.xml code for this module

```
          <sort_order translate="label">
                        <label>Sort Order</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </sort_order>
                    <sallowspecific translate="label">
                        <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </sallowspecific>
                    <specificcountry translate="label">
                        <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                    </specificcountry>
```